# M2MQtt connection using certificate in C#

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm attempting to connect to MQTT (Mosquitto) using the M2MQTT library in C#. The connection works fine when unauthenticated, however when enabling certificate authentication I am unable to connect.

I'm using the following code:

```
string Certificate = "C:\\temp\\numq1.p12";
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Certificate);
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("myserver.domain", 8883, true, new X509Certificate(cert));
string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
client.Connect(clientId);
```

The numq1.p12 has been generated using this command

> openssl pkcs12 -export -out numq1.p12 -inkey mqttcert.key -in
>   mqttcert.crt -certfile ca.crt

I've tried adding numq1.p12, mqttcert.crt and ca.crt to the Trust Root Certification Authorities, but the code still throws the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException' occurred in M2Mqtt.dll
Unable to connect to MQ server
uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException: Exception connecting to the broker ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttNetworkChannel.Connect()
   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)
   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId)
```

I wonder if someone is able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Further info...I'm able to subscribe to MQTT fine using mosquitto_sub and the same certificates which is leaving me baffled. Does M2MQTT, or any other .NET library for that matter, support client auth through certificates?

Comment: mosquitto_sub.exe -d -h myserver.domain -p 8883 -q 1 -t queue1/test1 --cert mqttcert.crt --key mqttcert.key --ca
file ca.crt

Answer (score 1):

I've had it confirmed by the developer of the M2MQTT library that SSL client authentication isn't supported, hence my futile efforts to get it working :(

I have therefore reverted to using SSL for server authentication, and passing through a username and password to MQTT. Whilst not ideal, it now works as expected.

Comment: You can file bugs against M2MQTT here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?component=M2MQTT&product=Paho&resolution=--- seems like this would be a generally useful feature.

Comment: Hi all, SSL server verification  now in 2017 asks for CaCert and Client Cert ? any luck does it work now? and what does it mean by the two certificate

Comment: @AnilGadiyar any luck with the certificates? I'm in the same position too, can't connect to the broker.

Comment: @BlackShawarna HI just  set return true and do no validation in the certificate validation function. cause that worked for me